# Does Sandboxie allow file deletion?

Tags: windows-7, sandboxie

Does `Sandboxie` allow the programs running inside the `DefaultBox` to delete files from the file system (or if not by default, is there an option for this)?
If not, are there any alternatives where I can prevent file deletion?
(Using Windows 7 (32 bit) operating system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent file deletion but you can block all access to that folder(s).
We are talking about file deletion inside the sandbox right?

Sandboxie uses a configuration file where it stores all settings to your sandboxes. 
That file is located under C:\windows\sandboxie.ini

Each sandbox starts with parentheses. For example: [DefaultBox]

```
[DefaultBox]
ClosedFilePath=!iexplore.exe,%Favorites%
```

The above means that every other program except internet explorer is denied access to the favorites folder.

Or you can just block the entiore folder, like this:
    ClosedFilePath=%Favorites%